# Device admin App ,startlocktask xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Good evening,
i'm trying to launch startlocktask on my deviceadmin app.
but when i launch the command `devicePolicyManager.SetLockTaskPackages(packageName) my app crash.`
i have tried to launch 
 `devicePolicyManager.IsDeviceOwnerApp(PackageName)` but the result is everytime false.
I can see my app under configuration device administrator.but i can't launch the command setstatusbar or startlocktask because the app seems like that this doesn't have the admin permission
my code is:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {   DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)GetSystemService(Context.DevicePolicyService);
                ComponentName demoDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(DeviceAdmin)));
                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ActionAddDeviceAdmin);
                intent.PutExtra(DevicePolicyManager.ExtraDeviceAdmin, demoDeviceAdmin);
                intent.PutExtra(DevicePolicyManager.ExtraAddExplanation, "Device administrator");
                StartActivity(intent);
                string x2 = demoDeviceAdmin.ClassName;
                string x3 = demoDeviceAdmin.ShortClassName;
                //  devicePolicyManager.SetStatusBarDisabled(demoDeviceAdmin, true);
                Toast.MakeText(this, devicePolicyManager.IsDeviceOwnerApp(PackageName).ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

my activity is:

```
 public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        [BroadcastReceiver(Permission = "android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN")]
        [MetaData("android.app.device_admin", Resource = "@xml/device_admin")]
        [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED", Intent.ActionMain })]
        public class DeviceAdmin : DeviceAdminReceiver
        {

            public override void OnEnabled(Context context, Intent intent)
            {

                base.OnEnabled(context, intent);
                Toast.MakeText(context, "DeviceAdmin", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }

            public override void OnDisabled(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                base.OnDisabled(context, intent);
            }

            public override void OnPasswordChanged(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                base.OnPasswordChanged(context, intent);
            }

            public override void OnPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                base.OnPasswordFailed(context, intent);
            }
            public override void OnPasswordSucceeded(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                base.OnPasswordSucceeded(context, intent);
            }
        }
```

my device_admin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-policies>
    <limit-password />
    <watch-login />
    <reset-password />
    <force-lock />
    <wipe-data />
    <expire-password />
    <encrypted-storage />
    <disable-camera />
  </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

my manifest is:

```
<receiver android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" android:name="md51e9ac75480e1224184ffdf189ecfeb54.MainActivity_DeviceAdmin">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

but no way..this doesn't work.
what's wrong?
can someone help me please?
thanks
regards
Andrea

Comment: You are never creating your `DeviceAdminReceiver` inner class and registering it unless you are doing this in code that you did not show. Move this class outside of your `Activity` so the OS can create it when the OS sends an intent action to it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have updated the code as you say:
but the result of 
Toast.MakeText(this, devicePolicyManager.IsDeviceOwnerApp(PackageName).ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
is everytime false